# Sketch: Text on Path not preserved when exported to SVG

Tags: vector, svg, sketch-app

I am creating a vectorized version of my school's logo because we currently only have a low-res bitmap version. The logo includes text on a circular path, so I used the Text on Path feature in Sketch to achieve the effect.

**The trouble is that when I export it to SVG (my desired format), the Text on Path does not export properly, and the text appears to be just normal lines of text. How can I fix this issue?**

[image: This is a screenshot of how the text appears in the Sketch app]

[image: This is how the text appears when exported to SVG (the text is highlighted for visibility)]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried converting the text to outlines?  How to [here](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/text/convert-to-outlines/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, not every SVG renderer supports text on paths, even though they are part of the SVG spec.

So I would recommend creating two files: one "original" file with the text on the path, and another with the text converted to a path or outline or whatever. Then export the second one to whatever other formats you need, like JPEG or PNG.

Comment: When I do this, it shifts the text from an outside curve to an inside, and moves it; it doesn't just convert it to outlines and leave it alone.

Comment: Try using a different software to do the conversion, such as InkScape.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the text, and click "Layer->Convert to Outlines" and then the text gets to be part of the image

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Sketch, but it may just be that your logo and/or text needs to be converted from an object to a path, as is the case because png formats for example can't handle unless you do a conversion to a path first.

Comment: Menu option Layer->Convert To Outlines should do it.

Comment: PNG format has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Convert to outlines results in the same problem, the text is removed from the path before converting it to outlines.